# SIGABRT on fopen call

Tags: c, linux, gcc, file-io, gdb

I'm writing a snippet of code to check if a file exists. When the user passes in a file argument with just a name ( no slashes ) I am to check to see if the file exists using paths in the PATH environment variable. I'm on Ubuntu compiling with gcc and have been using gdb. I found the line which is causing the SIGABRT but am unsure of what the information is telling me. This is my first time using gdb.  Here's my snippet:

```
char* PATH = NULL;
PATH = (char*)getenv( "PATH" );
char* pathtoken = strtok( PATH, ":" );
int index = 0;

while ( pathtoken != NULL )
{
    index++;
    printf( "%s\n", pathtoken );
    char* pathdir = (char*)malloc( sizeof(pathtoken) );
    strcpy( pathdir, pathtoken );
    GetFullPath( pathdir, filename );
    inputstream = fopen( pathdir, "r" );

    if ( inputstream != NULL)
    {
        free( pathdir );
        break;
        }

        free( pathdir );
        pathtoken = strtok( NULL, ":" );
    }

char* GetFullPath( char* dirpath, char* filename )
{
    //Append back slash
    int len = strlen(dirpath);
    dirpath[len] = '/';
    dirpath[len+1] = '\0';

    return strcat( dirpath, filename );
}
```

It happens on the first iteration at the fopen line. Here's my gdb output

> Starting program: /home/seapoe/Documents/OsClass/CodePractice/a.out text1
>   /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm
>
> Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0xbffff3a4) at xssh.c:87
>
> 87                 GetFullPath( pathdir, filename );
>
> (gdb) next
>
> 89                 inputstream = fopen( pathdir, "r" );
>
> (gdb) print pathdir
>
> $5 = 0x804c008 "/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/text1"
>
> (gdb) print pathdir[strlen(pathdir)]
>
> $6 = 0 '\000'
>
> (gdb) print pathdir[strlen(pathdir)+1]
>
> $7 = 0 '\000'
>
> (gdb) print pathdir[strlen(pathdir)+2]
>
> $8 = 0 '\000'
>
> (gdb) print pathdir[strlen(pathdir)-1]
>
> $9 = 49 '1'
>
> (gdb) next
>
> *** glibc detected**  /home/seapoe/Documents/OsClass/CodePractice/a.out: free(): invalid 
>   next size (normal): 0x0804c018 **
>
> ======= Backtrace: =========
>
> /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2)[0xb7e97ee2]
>
> /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x65db5)[0xb7e87db5]
>
> /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fopen+0x2b)[0xb7e87deb]
>
> /home/seapoe/Documents/OsClass/CodePractice/a.out[0x8048a77]
>
> /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb7e3b4d3]
>
> /home/seapoe/Documents/OsClass/CodePractice/a.out[0x8048771]
>
> ======= Memory map: ========
>
> 08048000-0804a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 536263     /home/seapoe/Documents/OsClass
>   /CodePractice/a.out
>
> 0804a000-0804b000 r--p 00001000 08:01 536263     /home/seapoe/Documents/OsClass/CodePractice/a.out
>
> 0804b000-0804c000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 536263     /home/seapoe/Documents/OsClass/CodePractice/a.out
>
> 0804c000-0806d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
>
> b7df3000-b7e0f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 394136     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
>
> b7e0f000-b7e10000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 394136     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
>
> b7e10000-b7e11000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 394136     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
>
> b7e21000-b7e22000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>
> b7e22000-b7fc5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 394115     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
>
> b7fc5000-b7fc7000 r--p 001a3000 08:01 394115     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
>
> b7fc7000-b7fc8000 rw-p 001a5000 08:01 394115     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
>
> b7fc8000-b7fcb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>
> b7fd9000-b7fdd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>
> b7fdd000-b7fde000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
>
> b7fde000-b7ffe000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 394095     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
>
> b7ffe000-b7fff000 r--p 0001f000 08:01 394095     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
>
> b7fff000-b8000000 rw-p 00020000 08:01 394095     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
>
> bffdf000-c0000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
>
> Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
>
> 0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()

After calling GetFullPath you can see a valid path is returned before the fopen call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char* pathdir = (char*)malloc( sizeof(pathtoken) );
```

is wrong.  sizeof(pathtoken) will give you the size of the pointer on your system (4 or 8).
You want

```
pathdir = strdup(pathtoken)
```

which is also wrong, given that you are trying to append to it.  Just make pathdir a char array of MAX_PATH (or PATH_MAX depending on your OS) length.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this:

```
sizeof(pathtoken)
```

The `sizeof` operator doesn't work that way, it's just giving you the size of a pointer variable, and isn't providing enough space. What you actually want is:

```
char* pathdir = malloc( strlen(pathtoken) + 1 );
```

or, as MK. states, this is what you'd want if you weren't trying to stuff even more characters in there during `GetFullPath()`. To compensate, either set up a big enough static array as he suggests, or do something like:

```
pathdir = GetFullPath( pathdir, filename );

....

char* GetFullPath( char* dirpath, char* filename )
{
    char * temp_path = malloc(strlen(dirpath) + strlen(filename) + 2);
    if ( temp_path == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No memory!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sprintf(temp_path, "%s/%s", dirpath, filename);
    free(dirpath);
    return temp_path;
}
```

Don't cast the return from `malloc()` in C.

Comment: Definitely like this better